# docker : invalid reference format issue

Tags: python, java, docker

I have just started learning docker and encountered an error in my first run. So, I was running the command, "docker run -p 5000:5000 in29min/hello-world-java:0.0.1:RELEASE". It ran successfully for python, then I closed the terminal and reopened it. Then I ran the same command only with a change of "java" instead of "python". And that's when I encountered the error.

Comment: What do you mean "ran successfully for python"? And what did you change? The word "python" doesn't appear in your first command.

Comment: so when i ran "docker run -p 5000:5000 in29min/hello-world-python:0.0.1:RELEASE" i was able to see the "hello world" message on my localhost:5000, but when i ran the same command with the change of "java" in place of python, it gave me the error.

Comment: Please edit your question rather than putting corrections in comments, and please include the entire error message.

Answer (score 1):

```
in29min/hello-world-java:0.0.1:RELEASE
```

This isn't a valid image name. A tag can contain `.` and `-` but not a `:` so `0.0.1:RELEASE` cannot be used for your tag.